# calculate differences between two numbers

Tags: php

i would like to calculate the differences between two given numbers for example:
1 - 5 or 24 - 35

I have to separate the numbers in arrays and to write the differences between them like:
1 2 3 4 5 or 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35

is there any php function that can handle that or any other php solution?

my code:

```
$string = array('1 - 5','9','11','24 - 35'); 

$arr = explode(",", $string);                        
  foreach ($arr as $val) {
    if (preg_match("/ - /", $val)) {

        $val = trim($val);
        $min= trim(substr($val, 0, 2));
        $max = trim(substr($val, -2));

      }
    }
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your code successfully determining `$min` and `$max`?  Once you have those values, you can just loop from one to the other to get the values between them.

Comment: You are probably looking for `range()`.

Comment: `$string = array(...` sounds wrong, and that's probably why the rest of your code won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using implode on the array unnecessarily. you need to process the array as an array to start with.

With the use of `range()` you can generate the numbers between `x - y` quite nicely.

There is also no need to get the regex engine involved in something as simple as `is there a hyphen in this string`

```
$string = array('1 - 5','9','11','24 - 35'); 

$new_arr = array();
foreach ($string as $val) {
    if (strpos($val,'-') !== false) {
        $v2 = explode('-', $val);
        foreach (range($v2[0],$v2[1]) as $v)
        $new_arr[] = $v;

    } else {
        $new_arr[] = $val;
    }
}       

print_r($new_arr);
```

RESULTS:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 9
    [6] => 11
    [7] => 24
    [8] => 25
    [9] => 26
    [10] => 27
    [11] => 28
    [12] => 29
    [13] => 30
    [14] => 31
    [15] => 32
    [16] => 33
    [17] => 34
    [18] => 35
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [range()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

```
<?php

foreach (range(24, 35) as $number) {
    echo $number."\n";
}


?>
```

Output:

```
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
```

http://codepad.org/kcozaHbp

Answer (score 0):

Your `$string` is not a string it is a array so no need to explode array and try to use [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to split strings. Use [range()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) and [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) without using loop like,

```
<?php
$arr = array('1 - 5','9','11','24 - 35'); 
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    $range = preg_split("/ - /", $val);
    if(count($range)==2 && $range[0]<$range[1]){
       echo implode(',',range($range[0],$range[1]));
       echo "\n";
    }
}  
?>
```

[Demo with Range without using Loop](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/70354a98be675e2fc716022a59fe4eeaa8f357b4)

Comment: It can be handled in `else` part. Actually I had answered only for range as OP asked.

Comment: and now, how can i put the array in the right order? because i need the array ranged and in the right order!

Comment: Push each range in a new array and use sorting on them Read http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `range()` to get array of numbers in range.

[Source](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6df698875894abb8f3dfa42950af1da1cbd0d403)

```
<?php
$numbers = ['1 - 5','9','11','24 - 35'];
$newNumbers = [];

foreach ($numbers as $i => $num) {
    $numRange = explode('-', str_replace(' ', '', $num));

    if (count($numRange) != 1) {
        $newNumbers = array_merge($newNumbers, range($numRange[0], $numRange[1]));
    } else {
        $newNumbers[] = $num;
    }
}

var_dump($newNumbers);

/**
Outputs

array(19) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(4)
  [4]=>
  int(5)
  [5]=>
  int(9)
  [6]=>
  int(11)
  [7]=>
  int(24)
  [8]=>
  int(25)
  [9]=>
  int(26)
  [10]=>
  int(27)
  [11]=>
  int(28)
  [12]=>
  int(29)
  [13]=>
  int(30)
  [14]=>
  int(31)
  [15]=>
  int(32)
  [16]=>
  int(33)
  [17]=>
  int(34)
  [18]=>
  int(35)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '1 - 5,9,11,24 - 35';

$arr = explode(',', $string);
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    if (count($values = explode('-', $val)) === 2) {
        $range = range(min(trim($values[0]), trim($values[1])), max(trim($values[0]), trim($values[1])));
        var_dump($range);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps

```
$string = array('1 - 5','9','11','24 - 35'); 

foreach ($string as $key => $val) {

    preg_match_all("/[0-9]+/", $val, $matches);

    if(count($matches[0]) == 1) {
        //single number
        $string[$key] = $matches[0][0];
    } elseif(count($matches[0]) == 2) {

        $n1 = intval($matches[0][0]);
        $n2 = intval($matches[0][1]);

        $vals = range($n1, $n2);
        $string[$key] = implode(" ", $vals);
    } else {
        throw new \RuntimeException("more than 2 numbers");
    }
}  

print_r($string);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 2 3 4 5
    [1] => 9
    [2] => 11
    [3] => 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
)
```

Comment: i tried this:  $nice = $arr[3];
   
    
   
    $arr2 = explode(",", $nice);
    foreach ($arr2 as $val1) {
       if (strpos($val1, ' - ') != FALSE) { 
       
       $val1 = trim($val1);
       $str1 = substr($val1, 0, 2);
       $str2 = substr($val1, -2);
       foreach (range($str1, $str2)) as $val2) { 
        
        echo $val2;
     
        
       }      
       }
    }